# Running iOS App In the background for getting data from Twitter

Tags: ios, twitter

I am in the process of developing a Twitter App on iOS, which will connect Twitter API in every 15 minutes, to Collect some data. I'm really not planing to have any server side script to Collect that data as I want everything inside the app itself.

Any idea on how to keep the app Running in Background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the Apple's guideline before proceeding to create such background jobs. If it fits with all such requirements then you can go ahead. Follow this link for further details:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html